# ADC input capacitor influence on ratiometric measurement and CMRR

Tags: adc, noise

I'm designing a data acquisition system where a resistive sensor (R1) and a load resistor (R2) form a voltage divider across the ADC's reference voltage.

[Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ads131m08)

In the current prototype there is no capacitor C1 (or any filtering) across the differential input and the performance is satisfactory (trace length is ~1.5 cm). In the next version we're interested in exploring higher values of R1 together with higher ADC input gains, so I am considering adding a small capacitor C1 across the differential input out of concern that the ADC's switched capacitor input stage might not charge fast enough when R1 is in the megaohm range.

However I'm concerned that adding C1 could couple noise from the voltage reference into the measured signal because the measurement would no longer be strictly ratiometric. Does this sound like a valid concern, and what is the correct way to reason about this?

Sampling rate is 1 kHz, the ADC is of the sigma-delta, simultaneous sampling type (no mux).

Noise and precision matter but accuracy is relatively unimportant, and I would like to avoid extra input buffering for reasons of space & cost, compromising on sampling rate if necessary.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8S25F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Without even addressing your question, my pref would be to not sample at vref, and to ground Ain_neg

Comment: @ScottSeidman I agree, but I would like to be able to increase the ADC gain (and with it the ADC input impedance) as the value of R1 increases. And unfortunately one of the sensor/R1 pins must be grounded.

Comment: @ScottSeidman note: the common mode input voltage range for this ADC extends beyond Vref.

Comment: It looks good. Add a cap between Vref & GND as well.